# DateTime Format Exception

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert the

```
string date = "31.03.2013"
```

to a `DateTime`. Here is my code:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(date,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I am getting a Format Exception.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165448.aspx it should work.
Thanks

Comment: The example in the link already shows how to do this properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The invariant culture is based on `en-US`, where `.` is not a the date separator.

You need to use the correct culture, such as `fr-FR`, which does use `.` as a date separator.

You could also use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` with the exact format string.

```
Convert.ToDateTime("31.03.2013", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"))
```

Or

```
DateTime.ParseExact("31.03.2013",
                    "dd.MM.yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Will work.

Comment: ... not to mention that `en-US` uses `MM/dd/yyyy`, and not `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Careful: `mm` stands for minutes, not months

Comment: @Nolonar - thanks. A suggested edit would also be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date,"dd.MM.yyyy",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the DateTime.ParseExact method. It should do the trick for you.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("31.03.2013", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code --

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) :

```
string date = "31.03.2013";
DateTime dateConverted;
DateTime.TryParseExact(date, new string[] { "dd.MM.yyyy" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateConverted);
Console.WriteLine(dateConverted);
```